# (React) Getting this error "The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax" after trying to build react app using " npm run build"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, npm-scripts, npm-build

**Please help me with this:**

My react application can run using npm start, everything is working fine with this command. However, when I try to deploy my application to google cloud, I am stuck at the step where I need to build the application using ***npm run build*** first.

**Here is my tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es6",
"lib": [
"dom",
"dom.iterable",
"esnext"
],
"allowJs": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"strict": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true,
"jsx": "react-jsx"
},
"include": [
"src"
]
}
```

**Here is my package.json**

```
{
"name": "client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.9.0",
"@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.2",
"@mui/material": "^5.6.2",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.12.0",
"@react-google-maps/api": "^2.12.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
"@types/node": "^16.11.26",
"@types/react": "^18.0.15",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
"@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
"helmet": "^5.0.2",
"http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.4",
"postcode-validator": "^3.6.6",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
"react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
"react-native-map-clustering": "^3.4.2",
"react-native-maps": "^1.1.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.6.3",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"build-css": "node combineCSS.js"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
"react-app",
"react-app/jest"
]
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
]
},
"type": "module",
"devDependencies": {
"@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^5.15.2",
"@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
"@types/google-map-react": "^2.1.7",
"@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.5",
"@types/react-modal": "^3.13.1",
"@types/react-router": "^5.1.18",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
"@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
"google-map-react": "^2.2.0",
"postcss": "^8.4.12",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
"recharts": "^2.1.13",
"tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
}
}
```

**Here are some of my import component statement in the project**

```
import { LoadingIcon } from './components/Icons'
import ScrollToTop from './components/ScrollToTop'
import InsightPage from './pages/InsightPage/InsightPage'
import Membership from './pages/MembershipPage/Membership'
```

**Full detail in terminal after bulding fail**

```
 react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...

warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
Failed to compile.

The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
```

Not much of detail but hopefully can help to figure the issue.

I think the issue is caused by the ts config file. However, I cannot find what config that makes this react application cannot be built using ***npm run build***.

Any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: Try changing, `module` inside tsconfig to `commonjS`

Comment: I have tried this, still no luck.

Any more suggestions, already stuck with this for hours.

Comment: Still cannot figure out what is the issue, hopefully to get help from someone

Comment: You want to use dynamic imports in your project ?

Comment: As you can find in my question description, there is some import statement that I used to import my own implemented component. And, I don't think it is a dynamic import because I don't put any condition to specify whether to import component or not.

Comment: Do you have some library import like `import { library } from 'https://urlforlibrary'` ?

Comment: I could not find one, and I think that I have not imported anything with the link. Do you have any suggestions to get more log error messages for this unsuccessful build?